# iOS Objective C ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

[image]I am trying to implement a UIScrollView and load it with images from an array of images in Xcode using objective-C, each image in the UIScrollView must be full screen both  in portrait and in the landscape mode.I have been able to  make it work in portrait mode  but not in landscape mode. It should be fullscreen in all iOS device sizes. Below is the code I have written so far. I have UIScrollView in my storyboard, a button and a label. Any answer or pointing to a tutorial that implements this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat widthInPixel = screen.size.width;
CGFloat heightInPixel = screen.size.height;
float increaseAmount = widthInPixel;
self.imageScrollView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
self.imageScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
[self.imageScrollView setAlwaysBounceVertical:NO];
[self.imageScrollView setAlwaysBounceHorizontal:NO];
imageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.imageScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
NSInteger imageNumbers  = [self.images count];
UIImageView *image;
for(NSInteger i = 0; i < imageNumbers; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
    image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
                          CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0,
                                     widthInPixel,

    self.imageScrollView.frame.size.height)];



    image.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    image.clipsToBounds = YES;
    image.image = self.images[i];

    [image setAutoresizingMask:
     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
     UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

    [self.imageScrollView addSubview:image];
}

self.imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(image.frame.size.width *
                                         imageNumbers,

self.imageScrollView.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: Instead of using a scroll view why not you using a UICollectionView which will reduce a lot of your code.

Comment: @NisarAhmad, I am required to implement it with UIScrollView, if you have any other suggestions please let me know, thanks, I appreciate

Comment: Than add  leading,Trailing, Top and Bottom constraints programmatically to imageView with respect to scroll view

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, do you have any tutorial or  an example on how to do this? I am relatively new to iOS programming, I started iOS programming 3 months ago. Thanks

Comment: @ucheGodfrey - do you want your images to Scale-to-Fill? Or Aspect-Fit? Or Aspect-Fill?

Comment: @DonMag, I want it Aspect-Fit

Comment: https://happyteamlabs.com/blog/ios-how-to-programmatically-add-auto-layout-constraints-for-a-view-that-will-fit-its-superview/ 
you can follow this link accordingly

Comment: @NisarAhmad, Thanks

Comment: Hi @DonMag, when the screen is rotated while scrolling two split images are shown on the screen. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @ucheGodfrey - see my edited answer...

Comment: @DonMag, Thanks a lot, it works perfectly now

Comment: @DonMag, how can I get the same effect on orientation change if I have a scrollview inside another scrollview to allow zooming in and out and all the other features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should learn how to use auto-layout and constraints. Use your favorite search engine and search for `ios auto layout tutorial` ... you'll find plenty of material.

---

**Edit:**

Scroll offset is an inherent issue when rotating a scroll view with **paging** enabled. See the edit below for an implementation of `viewWillTransitionToSize`.

---

But, to give you an idea, this will do what you want, including auto-resizing on device rotation:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  ScrollingImages
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 7/19/18.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *theScrollView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSArray *images = @[@"a", @"b", @"c", @"d", @"e"];

    [_theScrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
    [_theScrollView setAlwaysBounceVertical:NO];
    [_theScrollView setAlwaysBounceHorizontal:NO];

    // we'll use this to hold the most recently added view
    UIImageView *prevImageView = nil;

    for (int i = 0; i < images.count; i++) {

        // create an image view with named image from array
        UIImageView *v = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:images[i]]];

        // we want to use auto-layout
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        // we want aspect-fit
        v.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

        // add it to the scroll view
        [_theScrollView addSubview:v];

        // set width and height constraints equal to the scroll view
        [[NSLayoutConstraint
          constraintWithItem:v
          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
          toItem:_theScrollView
          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
          multiplier:1.0
          constant:0.0] setActive:YES];

        [[NSLayoutConstraint
          constraintWithItem:v
          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
          toItem:_theScrollView
          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
          multiplier:1.0
          constant:0.0] setActive:YES];

        if (i == 0) {  // if it's the first image

            // add top constraint
            [[NSLayoutConstraint
              constraintWithItem:v
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
              toItem:_theScrollView
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
              multiplier:1.0
              constant:0.0] setActive:YES];

            // and leading constraint
            [[NSLayoutConstraint
              constraintWithItem:v
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
              toItem:_theScrollView
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
              multiplier:1.0
              constant:0.0] setActive:YES];

        } else {

            // constrain leading to previous image view trailing
            [[NSLayoutConstraint
              constraintWithItem:v
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
              toItem:prevImageView
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
              multiplier:1.0
              constant:0.0] setActive:YES];

            // and top to previous image view top
            [[NSLayoutConstraint
              constraintWithItem:v
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
              toItem:prevImageView
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
              multiplier:1.0
              constant:0.0] setActive:YES];

        }

        if (i == images.count - 1) {  // if it's the last image

            // add trailing constraint
            [[NSLayoutConstraint
              constraintWithItem:v
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
              toItem:_theScrollView
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
              multiplier:1.0
              constant:0.0] setActive:YES];

            // and bottom constraint
            [[NSLayoutConstraint
              constraintWithItem:v
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
              toItem:_theScrollView
              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
              multiplier:1.0
              constant:0.0] setActive:YES];

        }

        // reference to most recently added view
        prevImageView = v;

    }

}

- (void) viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {

    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    // execute before rotation

    // get the "index" of the current image in the scroll view
    NSUInteger idx = (unsigned)(_theScrollView.contentOffset.x / _theScrollView.frame.size.width);

    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id  _Nonnull context) {
        // execute during rotation

        // update the scroll view's contentOffset, based on the "index"
        self.theScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(idx * self.theScrollView.frame.size.width, 0);

    } completion:^(id  _Nonnull context) {
        // execute after rotation (if additional code wanted)
    }];

}
@end
```

You can download a working example project here: https://github.com/DonMag/ScrollingImages